# How to format a date as localized Short MonthDay string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

I would like to format a DateTime to a string containing the month name abbreviated and the date for use in axis labels in a graph.

The default DateTime format strings do not contain abbreviated month. I guess there is no standard but I could take a substring of the first 3 characters of the month name and replace this into the MonthDay format. The reason I would use MonthDay is that the ordering of month and date is locale dependent.

Does anyone have a better idea?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#MonthDay

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could take the `MonthDay` pattern and replace "MMMM" with "MMM" - then apply that pattern:

```
string pattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern;
pattern = pattern.Replace("MMMM", "MMM");
string formatted = dateTime.ToString(pattern);
```

It's somewhat crude, but I believe it would work.

Comment: This won't work, if there is (or will be) a pattern "MMMMM" :) Too bad, the placeholders have no explicit limiter.

Comment: good solution Jon Skeet by the way how does it come up with something like 2014-sep-10 (yyyy-MMM-dd)

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe: What do you mean by "how does it come up with"?

Comment: i'm sorry for my english actually i was trying to have something like yyyy-MMM-dd ddd i have used convert ToString('yyyy-MMM-dd ddd') but not sure what would be the most efficient code.

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe: It's still not really clear what you mean. Perhaps you should ask a new question - it seems only tangentially related to this one.

Comment: simply is there any way to have a date string like this `yyyy-MMM-dd ddd` using your solution up here

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe: Again, this is completely different to the question being asked. If you know the format already, you just need to call `dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd ddd")`.

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe: Right, so I don't see the problem... again, if you have a different question, you should ask it as a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the custom string formatters to do this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("{0}", now.ToString("ddd MMMM dd"));
```

See the section "How Standard Format Strings Work" on the page you linked to for more info.

Comment: @Matt: That won't give a locale-dependent ordering though: "The reason I would use MonthDay is that the ordering of month and date is locale dependent."

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a CultureInfo in the Date.ToString() method. Either you have a specific culture info or you can use the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var ci = new CultureInfo("de-CH");
var output = date.ToString("d MMM", ci);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Use `date.ToString("d MMM")`. It will show *7 sep*.

Comment: He actually wants the shortened version, so it should be date.ToString("d MMM")

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with for the similar situation of wanting a localized version of `01/29`:

```
Regex.Replace(c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, @"(yy(yy)?[/\.\- ]|[/\.\- ]yy(yy)?)", "")
```

Here is the format output for all cultures, so you can see if it will work for you:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Select(c => new {
        c.Name,
        c.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern,
        c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern,
        DayMonth1 = Regex.Replace(c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, @"[/\.\- ]?yy[/\.\- ]?", ""),
        DayMonth2 = Regex.Replace(c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, @"(yyyy[/\.\- ]|[/\.\- ]yyyy|yy[/\.\- ]|[/\.\- ]yy)", ""),
        DayMonth3 = Regex.Replace(c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, @"(yy(yy)?[/\.\- ]|[/\.\- ]yy(yy)?)", "")
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .Dump();
```

The `DateMonth1` replace will remove an extra padding character for a couple cultures (specifically 'bg').

Answer (score -1):

Quick, easy and does the job.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(Month).Substring(0,3);
```

Comment: The output should include also the year and the date and the order of these items should be determined by the current culture.