# Best way to display locale-aware date with abbreviated month name?

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, internationalization

In my application, I use a sort of friendly short date format. For the en-GB locale, this is 'd MMM yyyy', i.e. 1 Jun 2014.

How can I produce a locale-aware format that uses the abbreviated month format and thus is friendly for any locale (as set by CurrentCulture)?

I thought something like this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cI = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

string niceFormat = cI.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace("MM","MMM").Replace("dd","d").Replace(cI.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator," ");
```

But - not every locale has 'MM', some use 'M' in the ShortDatePattern. And it I don't think I can reliably just replace the separator with " ". Or can I?

Any suggestions? Perhaps it would be better to start off with the LongDateTime format and strip it down?

Comment: Where do you get your date from? SQL server for example returning DateTime in specific format regardless of locale which you then can convert anyway you want.

Comment: Dates are from code / Entity Framework models etc.

Comment: take a look here: http://seankenny.me/blog/2013/09/19/web-api-entity-framework-and-is08601-date-formats/ maybe this will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include an abbreviated day of week, start with a long pattern and convert its day of week and month placeholders to short format:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
string formattedDate = date.ToString(
    culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern.Replace("dddd", "ddd").Replace("MMMM", "MMM"),
    culture);
```

Answer (score -1):

Take culture as you do

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

and then format it by using [Custom Date Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx) `DateTime.ToString` overload

```
date.ToString("d MMMM yyyy", culture);
```

---

[Proof](http://dotnetfiddle.net/eh9Wwe) (but it will explode, because fiddle memory is limited).

---

If you want displayed date to be user friendly (order and delimiters), then you rather avoid using anything else than `ShortDatePattern` offers already. You could try to replace `"M"` or `"MM"` with `"MMMM"`, but who told you it will still be *user friendly* then?

Perhaps you could use `MonthDayPattern` as John Skeet [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787271/1997232) (but still not recommended) and simply indicate year somehow (in brackets after that?).

Comment: If you do this `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures).Select(x=>x.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern).Dump();
` you'll see that not all cultures represent the day month and year in that order

Comment: And why would I do *that* ? I propose you to use **custom** date format, which will always produce result in the way you need.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to find a custom date format that will be 'friendly' in every language/locale. So, while your solution will be friendly to everyone in the UK (and many other locales), it might not be friendly to someone in another country, who'd rather see 'yyyy MMMM d'.

Comment: Now I understand what you want.